# Are Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) tokens unique?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't find any place in firebase docs, where indicated that received tokens are unique. I will be grateful if someone could point me such place. Main question - should I make unique constraint in database for such tokens. Thx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I search for [Are Google Cloud Messaging tokens unique](https://www.google.com/search?q=are+google+cloud+messaging+tokens+unique), the first result is [this page from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration), which says:

> To verify that they can send and receive messages, client apps must register with GCM. In this process, the client obtains a unique registration token...

Firebase Cloud Messaging Instance ID Tokens uniquely identify an instance of an app. They are globally unique.

Whether you should mark the column in your database as unique depends on your usage of that column. As yourself questions like: what bad thing will happen if a token is present twice in this table? Will marking the column unique prevent the bad thing from happening?

Comment: thank you for you feedback, but can you provide some links to documentation?

Comment: When I search for [Are Google Cloud Messaging tokens unique](https://www.google.com/search?q=are+google+cloud+messaging+tokens+unique), the first result is [this page from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration), which says "To verify that they can send and receive messages, client apps must register with GCM. In this process, the client obtains a unique registration token..."

Comment: Thank you, I searched for about half an hour, but didn't found that link. I think it's because my question was "are firebase push notifications tokens unique?" not "google cloud messaging"

Answer (score 10):

According to documentations, they're unique, but you can't bind them to a specific device since they might change.

[Documentation for IOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message#access_the_registration_token):

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

[Documentation for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#access_the_registration_token):

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

Comment: That they may change doesn't mean they are not unique.

Comment: @mcelicalderon You're completely right. I thought the PO asked about their uniqueness over time. (i'll edit the answer)

Comment: After uninstall app notification should receive on old token after application update?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ There's no guarantee :)

Comment: Let me ask a question. If I have two devices and both having an app that supports FCM push notifications, does the tokens obtained in these devices are different or not ?

Comment: @RoshanS Yes they are different. If the application on the second device is restored from the first device, it **might** have the same token (but is highly unlikely)... They all depend on `vendorIdentifier` and vendorIdentifier is reset based on so many rules (and also might stay the same under other rules). That's why documentations say **may change**. If you want to understand a bit more why generating absolute unique id's that can be bound to the device is hard (or impossible), read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor?language=objc

Comment: @RoshanS I realised I answered for only iOS. In a nutshell, Mobile producers don't want to violate their users privacy to be **trackable**, hence they won't provide enough information. Just unique as enough for third parties to be able to distinct their customers and track some short activities.

That's why Apple removed the support for getting Device Identifier (Absolutely unique) from their SDK, and I believe Android did the same thing with latest (or before that) Android SDKs

Answer (score 2):

As per my experience I have noticed that the FCM token is changed in three scenario they are as follows:-

1. When the application is uninstalled or reinstalled.
2. When the data of the application is cleared.
3. When the application is installed in new device.

Note:- There is no way to keep the FCM token same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are unique but they are not constant. Means for first time when I had installed one application then FCM token was let's say `abcd` but when I uninstalled the app and again installed the same app then my FCM token was not `abcd` but something else.

So, **FCM tokens are unique but they are not constant**, they keep on changing when we uninstall and install the application.