# How can I get any unique id flutter android and ios

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

I need to get a unique information of my device. This may be the mac address, it may be the imei address, or something different, ios and android return a constant value after a certain version and do not give the unique id.
The unique id as currently used changes when the application is deleted and reinstalled. I have a chat system and I don't want some members to come back.

Is there a way to access a device's unique information by obtaining a permission if necessary?

Comment: On iOS you can use the device check framework to store a "banned" flag for a particular device. Note that you are banning the device, not the user. The user can simply use a different device. Also if they sell their device to someone else, the device will still be banned.

Comment: It would be enough for me if I ban the device because the members I kicked persistently come and disturb other members easily. There must be a way to prevent this. I tried sms verification but it doesn't work well.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck

Answer (score 1):

you can use a package called [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) and get device token

`String deviceToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();`

To get the IMEI of user phone [device_information](https://pub.dev/packages/device_information)

`String imeiNo = await DeviceInformation.deviceIMEINumber;`

Comment: This is a nice approach, I hadn't thought of it before, but when does this token change and it should never change?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44551388/4659987

Comment: In my experience, I didn't get different device token but you can test the possible scenarios listed there. or if this way not working, you can get the IMEI number of specific user. check the edited code

Comment: Android has disabled the access of imei number due to security violation issues. This package now return UUID to differentiate the devices instead of real imei no.

Answer (score 0):

The token is generated per the client app instance.

> On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance.

See [Best practices for FCM registration token management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens) for details.

Only one user at the time is logged in on the app instance. [Delete](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/deleteToken.html) the token when a user logs out and then you get a new token when a new user logs in.